# iOs multi page browser (safari) like view

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to open multiple pages in my app just like iPhone( safari browser). Have two questions:

1. What is the best way to hold the views here, One view controller with an array of views to switch from ?
2. how to show safari like selection of views,where we can slide through a row or views and select one.

If you have any links or examples for this functionality pls share.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can also use https://github.com/adow/WKPagesCollectionView

Answer (score 4):

There is a open source library that implement something that look like the mobile safari (iPhone) multiple page selection. It is not using some uiwebview in the sample, but I guess it can be adapted to use uiwebview : https://github.com/100grams/HGPageScrollView

I'm also working on a Mobile safari clone, it's not yet implementing multiple pages selection, but I plan to add this when I'll be able to find some time to work on this. You can check this project here : https://github.com/sylverb/CIALBrowser

Answer (score -2):

look for uiscrollview uiwebview